# How to use natural logarithm inside Expression on FENICS

Tags: finite-element, fenics

I'm trying to evaluate the exact solution of heat diffusion in circular plate.

I'm not able to use the natural logarithm inside expression.

```
from math import log as ln

u_e = Expression("ln(5)")
```

The above line doesn't work. Could anyone help me with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes(" ") represent strings in python, and hence the argument of the function **`Expression()`** is a string literal rather than a floating-point number, i.e., **`ln(5)`**. To correctly specify **`ln(5)`** as an argument, remove the double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply

```
import math

u_e = Constant(math.log(5))
```